# Pointers: c++ requires a type specifier for all declarations

Tags: c++, c, pointers, types

I am currently learning c programming, and I've encountered a problem in one of the exercises I'm doing.

Whilst trying to decode how pointers work, i receive the following error:

c++ requires a type specifier for all declarations

my program:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdio.h>

    int a = 1, b = 2;
    double c = 3.1415;
    int *x, *y;

    x = &a;
    y = &b;


    int main() {

        printf("&a = %p\n", &a);
        printf("&b = %d\n", &b);
        printf("&c = %f\n", &c);
        printf("&x = %p\n", &x);
        printf("&y = % \n", &y);
        printf("x = %p\n", x);
        printf("y = %p\n", y);
        printf("a = %e\n", a);
        printf("b = %d\n", b);

        printf("*y = %d\n", *y);
        printf("c = %8.4f\n", c);
        printf("c = %4.2e\n", c);


    }
```

Its the

```
x = &a;
y = &b;
```

that shows up as errors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Kind regards

Comment: Move these statements inside the `main()` function.

Comment: This seems to be a horrible mixture of C and C++ (mostly C, but compiled as C++) - which language are you actually hoping to learn ? Despite appearances they are very different languages. I suggest you pick one and stick with it.

Comment: @EinarKnudsen would you consider to accept the answer?

Comment: Thank you, that resolved the problem!

Comment: I'm not sure why questions like this get downvotes - this is something that would definitely confuse a beginner C/C++ programmer.

Comment: Moving the statements inside the main() fixed it. Paul R, your observation is correct, it is a mixture. I would like to stick to the pure C programming, but as the classes I'm taking sometimes adds a little bit of C++ code, I'm forced to mix to be able to reproduce what we're taught at school. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @EinarKnudsen There is no “C with a bit of C++.” There is C and C++ and these two are different languages. If you are compiling with a C++ compiler you are writing C++, not C.

Answer (score 1):

It's because these are actual expression statements, and must go inside a function. Moving the offending lines into `main` will solve the problem:

Comment: That resolved the problem, thank you for answering!

Answer (score 1):

You can't have statements outside of functions. But you *can* have initializations on your declarations.

```
int *x, *y;

x = &a;
y = &b;
```

is not correct, but

```
int *x = &a, *y = &b;
```

is.

Even though I would write it like this to make it more readable (especially if you aim at C++):

```
int* x = &a;
int* y = &b;
```

Answer (score 0):

Statements cannot exist in global scope, so must be moved inside the `main` function. Declarations are allowed to exist in the global scope, however, which is why the lines above do not produce errors.

Comment: Moving the lines inside the main worked. Thank you for answering!

Answer (score 0):

In C++ outside functions you may place only **declaration statemens** (in C they are not called statements but just declarations) like

```
int a = 1, b = 2;
double c = 3.1415;
int *x, *y;
```

You may not write for example expression statements outside a function like

```
x = &a;
y = &b;
```

There was no any need to place the declarations outside main making them global. You could place them inside main making them local variables

```
int main() {
    int a = 1, b = 2;
    double c = 3.1415;
    int *x, *y;

    x = &a;
    y = &b;
```